# How to get the limit of the sequence $(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2-1})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, indeterminate-forms

**My Attempt**
$$
\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2-1} 
= \sqrt{n+1} \, \bigl(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1} \bigr)
$$
Then I tried to apply the sandwich theorem in some way but failed.

**Important Note**

Please do not solve the problem. Give hints only. Thanks!

**Further Progress**

Below is what I have got following the hint.

$\frac {\sqrt {1+\frac {1}{n}}}{1+\sqrt {1-\frac {1}{n}}}$ which should converge to $\frac {1}{2}$, but the answer (without any working) says $\frac {1}{3}$.

Indeed, the answer should be $\frac {1}{2}$. I have got everything. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Your factorisation is not correct.  Please check the RHS of your expression.

Comment: have you tried to multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-1}$?

Comment: When you have the limit of the difference of two roots you have to do the inverse rationalization

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Let me try.

Comment: You can pretty much mimic [the solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193965/the-limit-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx2-x-sqrtx2-1?noredirect=1), for example.

Comment: The limit is $1/2$, NOT $1/3$.

Comment: Plugging in $n = 10^6$ gives $0.5000003749737516$, which seems to indicate that the limit *is* 1/2.  Where did you get 1/3?

Comment: A duplicate, I think. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2531772/11619) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949300/11619).

Answer (score 3):

The genral method to this kind of problem is called $\textbf{Rationalization}$, which means:

$$\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2-1}$$

$$= (\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt{n^2-1}) \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2-1}}$$

Then, obviously we can rearrange the divisor part as:

$$\frac{(n^2+n) - (n^2-1)}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2-1}}$$

$$= \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + \sqrt{n^2-1}}$$

$$= \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}}$$

Until this step, it is clear that the limit of the whole expression is:

$$1 \cdot \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, we note that if $k$ is fixed, we have
$$
\sqrt{n + k} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}} \to 0 \quad \mbox{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$

Therefore,
$$
\sqrt{n^2 + n} - \left(n+\frac12\right) = \sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt{n^2+n+\frac14} \to 0
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{n^2-1} - n = \sqrt{n^2-1} - \sqrt{n^2} \to 1
$$
as $n \to \infty$, which means that for the requested limit we obtain
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt{n^2-1}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\left(n + \frac12\right) - n \right) = \frac12. 
$$.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints for squeezing.

$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$

$x\ge y \implies \frac{x-y}{2\sqrt{x}}\le \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}\le \frac{x-y}{2\sqrt{y}}$

---

OR

$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{x}(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}})\approx \sqrt{x}[1-(1-\frac{1}{2x})]=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$